# Computing the minimum value for each row in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, minimum

I have this DataFrame `df`:

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   2   1
3   4   1   2
4   6   3   2
5   4   5   6
```

I would like to add a column that calculates the minimum values, by slicing columns A to D (the actual `df` is larger, so I need to slice it) ie

```
Dmin
1
1
2
4
```

I can calculate the min for 1 row as follows

```
df.iloc[0].loc['A':'D'].min()
```

I tried the following for the whole DataFrame, all of which gave `NaN`

```
df['Dmin']=df.loc[:,'A':'D'].min()

df['Dmin']=df.iloc[:].loc['A':'D'].min()

df['Dmin']=df.loc['A':'D'].min()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df['Dmin'] = df.min(axis=1)
```